# Limit the Link field to certain domains

Tags: 7, entities, navigation

I'm looking for a module that will let me limit users to certain domain names when they edit a Link field.

For example, only let users enter a URL if the domain name is `facebook.com`, `twitter.com` or `plus.google.com`.

This list must be easily editable by admins.

Does such a module exist?

(Also: See my [other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22410/module-to-display-a-websites-favicon-when-displaying-a-link-to-it), if there is some a module that can do both it'll be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Field Validation module](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation)

> This module adds an extra tab to each field instance, allowing you to specify validation rules for your field instances.

From there you could a custom PHP function/regular expression to match the URLs against the field value.

This will only editable by admin in the sense that they can also edit the PHP code/regular expressions in the field validation rule. I'm not aware of a specific module that will do everything that you want without any customisation.

Comment: I love running across new modules like this.  Thank you for sharing. :)  Regex examples to note: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL

Comment: @Citricguy Me too, I wouldn't even have found it had it not been for this question...now off to install it in several sites :)

Comment: I would've preferred a more complete module, but since the clients are willing to get their hands dirty and edit fields, it could work. Thanks!