# Module to display a website's favicon when displaying a link to it

Tags: 7, entities, navigation

I'm looking for a module that will display a website's favicon when display a link to that site. Specifically, I want to enable it to one certain Link field.

For example, if a user edits a node and uses the URL `https://www.facebook.com/pages/Drupal/8427738891` in a Link field, I want to display the favicon `https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico`.

Ideally, the module can cache the favicon locally (there are several benefits for this)

(Also: See my [other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22409/limit-the-link-field-to-certain-domains), if there is some a module that can do both it'll be great)

Answer (score 0):

i believe this will work for you https://www.drupal.org/project/link_favicon_formatter

hope this helps:)